# Trouble understanding meaning of this subspace question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{U_n : n \in \Bbb N \}$ be a family of subspaces in $\Bbb R^m$.

Show that if $U_{n+1} \subseteq U_n$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$ there exists an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $U_n = U_N$ for all $n \ge N$.

What exactly is this question asking? To me it looks like I have to show that all U in the set are the same subspace if $U_n$ is a subset of the one before it. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

It's a "descending" sequence of subspaces.

Since $m$ is finite you would expect that either you would get down to the zero vector space (i.e. dimension zero, containing only the zero vector) or you would stop getting smaller at some subspace of dimension $N$ with  $m \ge N > 0$. In either case you then have all subsequent subspaces being the same dimension.

Try and prove it in two lines by contradiction.